# Condition IF is_search() Results Page for Default Post Type only

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

The built in wordpress function `is_search()` determines whether the query is for a search ([source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_search/)). In this form, the function does not distinguish between post types.

What im trying is to load a script only on the search results page for posts but not the search results for products. For example:

```
    function child_theme_search_custom_js_script() {
        if ( is_search() ) { // But only for default post type?
            wp_enqueue_script( 'child-theme-cart-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/child-search-custom-js.js', array('abc-core'), '1.0.0', true );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_search_custom_js_script' );
```

Any way to check if it is the results page for the default post type?

Comment: The default search doesn't include much out of the box as it is. Can you clarify your question or give a better example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: What im trying is to load a script only on the search results page for posts but not the search results for products. Edited my question. thx

Answer (score -1):

So i played around with different wordpress conditions and found a solution to target only the search results page for the default post type.

```
    // If it is "Post" Post Type Search Results Page only
    if ( ! is_post_type_archive() && is_search()  )  {
```